# Finding the number of integer points inside a sphere of radius R and dimension D centered at the Origin

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, number-theory

I am writing a computer program/algorithm to count the number of integer points inside a sphere of radius R and Dimension D centered at the origin. In essence, if we have a sphere of dimension 2 (circle) and radius 5, I am determining all integer solutions to the inequality X^2+Y^2 ≤ 25. Instead of counting every possible integer point, is there an efficient way to count the points ? Using symmetry ?

Comment: @Sean Cline: The question regards counting _all_ integer points within the sphere, roughly equal to its volume. I should think it is more of a question of (discrete) mathematics. I wouldn't be surprised if there was a clever analytic (`O(1)`) formula for this.

Comment: Why do you need new question similar to existing one? Edit old question, add new thoughts and tags, if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the dimension is 3, and R is the radius. For z = 0, the possible x,y coordinates are the points inside a circle of radius R, and for any z, the x,y's are the points inside a circle of radius sqrt( R * R - z * z); the possible values of z are -r, .. 0, 1, .. r where r is the smallest integer less than R. Note the count for z and -z will be the same.

When we get down to dimension 1, we are asking how many integers i satisfy |i| < R, and this is 1 + 2 * r

So:

```
int ncip( int dim, double R)
{   
    int i;
    int r = (int)floor( R);
    if ( dim == 1)
    {   return 1 + 2*r; 
    }
    int n = ncip( dim-1, R); // last coord 0
    for( i=1; i<=r; ++i)
    {   n += 2*ncip( dim-1, sqrt( R*R - i*i)); // last coord +- i
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, using symmetry, you can always just count all the integer solutions on the positive side, and then invert the components. So, in case of your Circle (D=2, R=5), you'd just have to find
{ X,Y ∈ N: X²+Y² ≤ R }. Then create the combinations (X,Y), (X,-Y), (-X,Y), (-X,-Y)
This leaves you with just (1/2)<sup>D</sup> solutions to find.

Also, you can approximate a circle of radius R as a Square with radius R/√2, so all combinations of integers smaller than or equal to that can automatically be added.